# ASP.NET Core getting a value from an input box with a c# variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a project in which there needs to be a search box to find records containing the input string and then display them onto the page. Ideally, the requirement is to filter out results as the string is being typed in, but if that's impossible, just a search button to find the end results will work. I do not know much about ASP.NET Core, so I do not know how to do this in the slightest bit.
At first, I thought I may be able to do this by taking the input value and putting that into an sql statement, then displaying it, something like:

(Context: using Visual Studios 2017 enterprise, in a .cshtml file)

```
<input id="pleaseWork" type="text" />
<button onclick="@workAlready()">search</button>

@{
    public void workAlready(){
        var inpString = document.getElementByID("pleaseWork").value

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (ID = '" + inpString + "')";
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(Connection);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connect);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader nwReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        /*...Display results*/
    }
}
```

This would work okay - (okay being relative to the problem, disregarding bad coding practices and ugly code) - if I was able to do this and get the input field value into a c# variable, but with both types of variables not playing well with each other, I cannot find any way of doing this. I've searched a lot of places, and I hear a lot talking about using controllers and the like, but with my limited knowledge of .NET Core (as well as MVC altogether,) I cannot get it to work. So I guess my question is wondering if its possible to do it this way? Can I get an input value as a c# variable? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: coding practices are created to be followed, what's the reason you are not using MVC as it is intended to be?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend learning the MVC framework, as well as a new language. What you're trying to right now is calling a pre-processed method in a processed page (hint: it's impossible). What you need to do is define controllers and actions in your server side codebase (i.e. the controller layer, the C in MVC).

You can use whatever language in the frontend to call this controller (I would recommend just using jQuery since you're so new to all this). JQuery is javascript, and therefor you can actually call functions you define in a jQuery script from a click on an input field.

So do two things, learn how to send an AJAX request (POST) to a server. Secondly, learn how to properly create a simple controller - action in your codebase.

Once you have those 2 set, you can communicate between your view and controller. Then after that you can start thinking about SQL, but no sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data to your Controller via [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Your Controller might look like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
    [HttpPost]
    public String HandleValue([FromBody] string inpString) 
    {      
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (ID = '" + inpString + "')"; 
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(Connection);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connect);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader nwReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        // format and return the results
    }
}
```

Then post the data to the Controller from your JavaScript:

```
var inpString = document.getElementByID("pleaseWork").value;

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: inpString
}
fetch('/Home/HandleValue', options).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(results) {
  // display results, it contains the data you returned from the controller  as json.
});
```

Or you can use good old [Forms](https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly I just had this same issue. What I essentially did is the following:

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <input name="pleaseWork" type="text" />
        <button asp-page-handler="DoWork">search</button>
    }
</div>
```

Then in your [PageModel].cshtml.cs file...

```
public void OnPostDoWork() {
    var inpString = HttpContext.Request.Form["pleaseWork"];

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (ID = '" + inpString + "')";
    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(Connection);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connect);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader nwReader = command.ExecuteReader();
    /*...Display results*/
}
```

Note: I'm currently using asp .net core 2.1